# Drush can't connect to MySQL through socket

Tags: drush, database, installation

When trying to install a new drupal with

```
drush si standard --db-url=mysql://root@localhost/drushtest
```

I get the following error Message:

> [...] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket [...]

MySQL User is root with no password and the database drushtest was already created. I'm using Ubuntu with Xampp and *guessing* that the incorrect mysql.sock is used.

```
ps -ax|grep mysql
```

says that my mysql.sock lies within

```
/opt/lampp/var/mysql
```

Has somebody a clue how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using 127.0.0.1 in place of localhost

Comment: Weird. Same problem, same solution. Any explanation for this, @Clive?